# How to efficiently set default value for missing columns when extracting columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I want to get values for "Banana", "Mango" and "Orange" columns in my pandas dataframe.

Supposse, one of my pandas dataframes looks as follows. In other words, it does not have a column named "Mango".

```
         Apple  Orange  Banana  Pear
Basket1     10      20      30    40
Basket2      7      14      21    28
Basket3     55      15       8    12
```

In such situations, I want to set the value to "None". So, my output is;

```
         Banana  Mango Orange
Basket1  30      None   20
Basket2  21      None   14
Basket3  8      None    15
```

I want to do this process in one line. Just wondering if It is possible to do so in pandas?

My code is as follows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[10, 20, 30, 40], [7, 14, 21, 28], [55, 15, 8, 12]],
                  columns=['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Pear'],
                  index=['Basket1', 'Basket2', 'Basket3'])
df[df.columns & ["Banana", "Mango", "Orange"]] #I check what are the columns that exists
```

My output so far looks follows.

```
         Banana Orange
Basket1  30      20      
Basket2  21      14      
Basket3  8       15
```

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: `df['Mango']=None`?

Comment: is your expected output the first or second?  either ways, you can use `reindex` : ``df.reindex(columns = ["Banana", "Mango", "Orange"])`` or ``df.reindex(columns=df.columns.intersection(["Banana", "Mango", "Orange"]))``

Comment: @wwnde Thanks for the comment. However, I don't know which column would be empty.  So, the identification of which columns are empty and setting their values to "None" should be happen dynamically.

Comment: @sammywemmy I tried your query `df.reindex(columns = ["Banana", "Mango", "Orange"])`. However, it set "Nan" instead of "None" (or some value I wish to set default). Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Try `df.reindex(columns = ["Banana", "Mango", "Orange"], fill_value="None")` , this fills missing columns with the "None" string. You can't use None directly because pandas coerces it to np.nan (FOR PERFORMANCE REASONS).